# Deserialize the xml configuration file present in different location

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to Deserialize XML configuration file stored in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Configuration\Configuration.XML. I want to read the key value section and store it in the local variable.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="FolderPath" value="C:\\Data" />
            <add key="Name" value="xxx" />
            <add key="Type" value="xxx" />
        </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

`ConfigurationManager.Appsettings.Get("FolderPath")` does not work because the xml file is in the different location.
So I tried with the following code, which does not work.

```
var configFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData"), "Configuration", "Configuration.XML")
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);
var  appSettings = configuration.GetSection("appSettings").SectionInformation;
```

Please help me to read the configuration.XML as shown above.
Thank you.

Comment: Get the environmental variable LOCALAPPDATA : Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(" LOCALAPPDATA ");

Comment: Yes, I am using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() to get the path. The problem is I am not able to read the key value from the Configuration.XML which is stored in a different location.

Comment: Then add the string "\Configuration\Configuration.XML" to the path name.

Comment: @jdweng,  Please see the code above. I am using "Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData"), "Configuration", "Configuration.XML"))" and I am giving complete path to the ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile).

Comment: What error are you getting?  Did you check to see if file is in the folder (configFile)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions @jdweng.
I was able to solve the issue

```
var configFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA"),  "Configuration", "Configuration.XML"));
if (File.Exists(configFile))
{
   ConfigurationDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(configFile);
   var elements = doc.Descendants("add");
   foreach (var element in elements)
   {
      ConfigurationDetails.Add(element.Attribute("key").Value, element.Attribute("value").Value);
   }
}
```